# Why i am getting window.FirebasePlugin is null in given sample code?

Tags: cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7, cordova-plugin-fcm

i have install cordova fcm plugin also i am adding google-services.json in root folder , i have done successfully set up for fcm yet i am unable to get token

i have phonegap desktop app where i can run my application and i can check on my android device

```
try {

        if (window.FirebasePlugin == null) {
            alert("FCMPlugin is null")
            return;
 }

         window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function (token) {


             alert(token);
          });

       }

catch (e) {

        alert(e);

       }


    }
```

i am getting alert as FCMPlugin is null

Comment: Paste your config.xml

Answer (score 0):

One our most common case its set FirebasePlugin call direct before its check if device or file is ready or not, so that put your code inside device ready event (Or make sure to load after every thing is called), for example:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', DeviceReady, false);

function DeviceReady(){
    console.log(window.FirebasePlugin);
}
```

Second case its you not loaded `Cordova.js` (If its not loaded, make sure to call it), or its load too late (So that the deviceReady event will resolve issue)

good luck.